# C# Console Application, how to make all results equals totalResult?

Tags: c#, console-application

1. How do I make the last result equal the first, second, third, and fourth result combined?
2. If all results are 10 points except the last one, then the last one should be 40 points. The last result is the total result.

   ```
   int[] result = new int[5] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
   ```

Comment: More specifically: What have you already tried doing?

Comment: Welcome! put your code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: I think he will sum up array pos from 0 - 3 and save the result in pos 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
int[] result = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 0 };
result[result.Length - 1] = result.Take(result.Length - 1).Sum(); // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
//result = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 10 };
```

Comment: The Take should be Length -2, no? Otherwise calling it a second time will double up the value since it will count itself.

Comment: @SteffenColeBlake calling it a second time will overwrite the `10` with a new calculated `10`

Comment: But before it does that, it will count itself. So it will double every call. [1,2,3,4,0] => [1,2,3,4,10] => [1,2,3,4,20] etc etc. The Take call should be result.Length -2 not -1

Comment: Also you can just do .Last() on Arrays I am fairly certain.

Comment: @SteffenColeBlake I don't get your point can you show me in this fiddle? https://dotnetfiddle.net/naKGBD

Comment: Oh you know what, I was thinking of SubArray stuff, I thought Take() was index based, not n based. Take(1) gets index 0.